# readonly resultbox change color based on calculation

Tags: javascript, html, function, colors, display

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function display(){
      var resultBox = document.getElementById("resultbox");
      var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
      var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");

      var result = input1.value * input2.value;
      resultBox.value = result;
  }
</script>
```

im using this but i want the result to go green if the answer is from 1-3 and goes yellow if its 4-9 and orange if its 10-19 and 20 if red > the above code worked but when i added the change color function it wont change color

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function display(){
      var resultBox = document.getElementById("resultbox");
      var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
      var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");

      var result = input1.value * input2.value;
    
      resultBox.value = result;
  }

  if (resultBox <=3) {
  resultBox = document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "green";
} else if (resultBox<=9) {
  resultBox = document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "yellow";
  
  
} 
else if (resultBox <=19) {
  resultBox = document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "orange";
}
else {
  resultBox = document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "red";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On lines like these:

```
resultBox = document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "orange";
```

You've combined getting the `p2` element and setting its colour, but it's incorrect. The result will be that your colour changes, but `resultBox` has the value `orange` in it.

If you want to do this, use two separate lines:

```
resultBox = document.getElementById("p2");
resultBox.style.color = "orange";
```

Or brackets to enforce order (not recommended):

```
(resultBox = document.getElementById("p2")).style.color = "orange";
```

More importantly, your code is only being executed once -- only when the page is first loaded. Try placing your code to change the resultbox text colour inside the `display()` function so it gets run every time `display()` is called:

(I also tidied up your indentation and code a bit in this snippet.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function display(){
      var resultBox = document.getElementById("resultbox");
      var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
      var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");

      var result = input1.value * input2.value;
    
      resultBox.value = result;

      if (resultBox <=3) {
        resultBox.style.color = "green";
      } else if (resultBox<=9) {
        resultBox.style.color = "yellow";
      } else if (resultBox <=19) {
        resultBox.style.color = "orange";
      } else {
        resultBox.style.color = "red";
      }
  }
</script>
```